# Pretty URLs and dynamic Vars

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am in the outlining phase of constructing a Routing system for a PHP Framework I am building.

I will need to use mod rewrite, for pretty urls. I got that part covered.
But say I want to make a page with the url like:

www.domain.com/news/10(News-id)/

and I want this dynamic variable ( This news id ) to have a name when rewriting.

What I want to achieve is;

Frameworks routes to news controller, and passes 10 as argument as:
$args = array ( 'news_id' => 10 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$_SERVER` super-global to inspect the requested URI.  In your example, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will be set to something like:

```
/news/10/
```

You can then get the requested news-id from that string.

**Update**

```
// Use substr to ignore first forward slash
$request = explode('/', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1)); 
$count = count($request);

// At this point, $request[0] should == 'news'
if($count > 1 && intval($request[1])) {
    // The second part of the request is an integer that is not 0
} else {
    if( $count == 1) {
        // This is a request for '/news'

    // The second part of the request is either not an integer or is 0
    } else if($request[1] == 'latest') {
        // Show latest news
    } else if($request[1] == 'oldest') {
        // Show oldest news
    } else if($request[1] == 'most-read') {
        // Show most read news
    }
}
```

See the [manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for `$_SERVER`

Comment: But the tricky part comes when that url is not always a news-id.
- it might be: news/latest/

Comment: Alright, so I have to wire it up internally, from PHP. Was hoping for some cool mod_rewrite thing, but meh... :) Thanks.

Comment: @Kao It is possible with mod_rewrite, but my personal preference is to use PHP as the router.  It's cleaner plus more moduler (it's a lot easier to use the same controllers/routers on other projects)